# how to append row vectors to an empty matrix without knowing the size of the matrix using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

rows is a 343x30 matrix of real numbers. Im trying to append row vectors from rows to true rows and false rows but it only adds the first row and doesnt do anything afterwards. Ive tried vstack and also tried putting example as a 2d array ([example]) but it crashed my pycharm. what can I do?

```
true_rows = []
        true_labels = []
        false_rows = []
        false_labels = []
        i = 0
        for example in rows:
            if question.match(example):
                true_rows = np.append(true_rows , example , axis=0)
                true_labels.append(labels[i])
            else:
                #false_rows = np.vstack(false_rows, example_t)
                false_rows = np.append(false_rows, example, axis=0)
                false_labels.append(labels[i])
            i += 1
```

Comment: a small example of input/output would be helpful

Comment: have you tried np.concatenate?

Comment: @yann ziselman yes I tried to concatenate and it works for the first iteration, there I get a 2by30 matrix but at the second time I concatenate it with another vector its says there is a dimmention missmatch, this is what it says:
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 3 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)

Answer (score 1):

you can use only a simple list to append your rows and then transform this list to numpy array such as :

```
exemple1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
exemple2 = np.array([6,7,8,9,10])
exemple3 = np.array([11,12,13,14,15])  

true_rows = []
true_rows.append(exemple1)
true_rows.append(exemple2)
true_rows.append(exemple3)
true_rows = np.array(true_rows)
```

you will get this results:

```
true_rows = array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
                   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
                   [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]])
```

you can also use `np.concatenate` if you want to get one dimensional array like this:

```
true_rows = np.concatenate(true_rows , axis =0)
```

you will get this results:

```
true_rows = array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15])
```

Comment: will it be a numpy array or list in the end?

Comment: it will be a numpy array in the end

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `[]` and `np.append` suggests you are trying to imitate a common list append model with arrays.  You atleast read enough of the `np.append` docs to know you need to use `axis`, and that it returns a new array (the docs are quite clear this is a **copy**).

But did you test this idea with a small example, and actually **look** at the results (step by step)?

```
In [326]: rows = []
In [327]: rows = np.append(rows, np.arange(3), axis=0)
In [328]: rows
Out[328]: array([0., 1., 2.])    
In [329]: rows.shape
Out[329]: (3,)
```

the first append doesn't do anything - the result is the same as `arange(3)`.

```
In [330]: rows = np.append(rows, np.arange(3), axis=0)
In [331]: rows
Out[331]: array([0., 1., 2., 0., 1., 2.])
In [332]: rows.shape
Out[332]: (6,)
```

Do you understand why?  We join 2 1d arrays on axis 0, making a 1d.

Using `[]` as a starting point is the same starting with this array:

```
In [333]: np.array([])
Out[333]: array([], dtype=float64)
In [334]: np.array([]).shape
Out[334]: (0,)
```

And with `axis`, `np.append` is just a call to `concatenate`:

```
In [335]: np.concatenate(( [], np.arange(3)), axis=0)
Out[335]: array([0., 1., 2.])
```

`np.append` sort looks like list append, but it is not a clone.  It's really just a poorly named way to use `concatenate`.  And you can't use it properly without actually understanding dimensions.  `np.append` has an example with an error much like what you got with concatentate.

Repeated use of these array `concatenates` in a loop is not a good idea.  It's hard to get the dimensions right, as you found.  And even when it works, it is slow, since each step makes a copy (which grows with the iteration).

That's why the other answer sticks with list append.

`vstack` is like `concatenate` with axis 0, but it makes sure all arguments are 2d.  But if the number columns differ, it raise an error:

```
In [336]: np.vstack(( [],np.arange(3)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-336-22038d6ef0f7>", line 1, in <module>
    np.vstack(( [],np.arange(3)))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in vstack
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py", line 282, in vstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 0 and the array at index 1 has size 3

In [337]: np.vstack(( [0,0,0],np.arange(3)))
Out[337]: 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 2]])
```

If all you are joining are rows of a (n,30) array, then you do know the column size of the result.

```
In [338]: res = np.zeros((0,3))
In [339]: np.vstack(( res, np.arange(3)))
Out[339]: array([[0., 1., 2.]])
```

If you pay attention to the shape details, it is possible to create an array iteratively.

---

But instead of collecting rows one by one, why not create a `mask` and do the collection once.

Roughly do

```
mask = np.array([question.match(example) for example in rows])
true_rows = rows[mask]
false_rows = rows[~mask]
```

this still requires an iteration, but overall should be faster.